# Rotation Keybinds

Tags: objects

I would like to know if there is a keybind for grabbing the Y-Axis on the rotation tool. I have a "bug" (idk if it is) where I can only grab the Z-Axis and nothing else. If somebody can help me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it should just be R > Z in object mode or in edit mode

if you get stuck on rotating and axis then press the right mouse button to cancel.

also you can go to user prefs > input and search for any key combos you want. and even change them.